# Summary statistics by category using Stagazer package

Tags: categorical-data, summary, stargazer

I want to use the [stargazer package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stargazer/vignettes/stargazer.pdf) to have a ready to publish summary statics for each subgroup of crops for a table like this:

| crop | yield |
| --- | --- |
| corn | xx |
| wheat | yy |
| soybean | zz |

I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25389683/obtaining-separate-summary-statistics-by-categorical-variable-with-stargazer-pac), but it was not exactly what I was looking for.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you not like from the suggested solution? Please specify your data and the output format. For grouped descriptive summary statistics, I would opt for `gtsummary` package. The main difference is the output format. `stargazer` is good at text and latex, gtsummary produces great html output.

```
# Agricultural data on crops and yield
library(agridat)
data("bose.multi.uniformity")

table(bose.multi.uniformity$crop)

# Grouped descriptives

# tidyverse and stargazer output, i.e. text or latex
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)

bose.multi.uniformity %>%
  group_by(crop) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gather(temp, val, yield) %>%
  unite(temp1, crop, temp, sep = '_') %>%
  select(-c(year, row, col)) %>% 
  spread(temp1, val) %>%
  select(-id) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  stargazer(type = 'text')

===========================================
Statistic     N   Mean   St. Dev. Min  Max 
-------------------------------------------
barley_yield 390 634.244 161.091  180 1,040
lentil_yield 390 215.713  63.464  81   431 
wheat_yield  390 251.838  71.824  70   450 
-------------------------------------------

# tidyverse and tbl summary, i.e. html 
library(gtsummary)

bose.multi.uniformity %>% 
  select(crop, yield) %>% 
  tbl_summary(statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({min}, {max})"), by = crop) %>% 
  as_gt()
```

[image]

Best